# cancel button does not redirect me to the tab view of lead page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have written following code to override the new page of lead form. Functionality working absolutely fine. When i click on new button and then click on cancel it will not redirect me to the tab view.

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" 
  action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.New,$ObjectType.Lead,[lea3=$User.companyname],true)}">
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 <apex:page standardController="Lead" 
  action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.New,$ObjectType.Lead,[lea3=$User.companyname,retURL=$ObjectType.Lead.keyprefix],true)}">
</apex:page>
```

Keyprefix will return you to the view page

Thanks
Ankush